# Android BroadcastReceiver called multiple times

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, hotspot

I'm new to android and i am trying to implement a broadcast receiver which will receive the broadcast whenever the hotspot is changed:

```
public class HotspotChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements Configurable {

public static boolean isEnabled = false;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //TODO handle properly
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if ("android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED".equals(action)) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, 0);

       // if (WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED == state % 10) {
         if(state == 13){
            intent1.setAction("net.wecodelicious.intent.action.HOTSPOT_ENABLED");
            context.sendBroadcast(intent1);
        }
        else{
            intent1.setAction("net.wecodelicious.intent.action.HOTSPOT_DISABLED");
            context.sendBroadcast(intent1);
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, "HOTSPOT Changed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public static void enable() {
    if(!isEnabled) {
        MainActivity.getMpackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.getMcontext(), HotspotChangeReceiver.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        isEnabled = true;
    }
}


public static void disable() {
    if(isEnabled) {
        MainActivity.getMpackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.getMcontext(), HotspotChangeReceiver.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        isEnabled = false;
    }
}
}
```

also i've following classes to receive custom broadcasts:

```
public class HotspotEnabledReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements Configurable {
public static boolean isEnabled = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //TODO handle properly
    if("net.wecodelicious.intent.action.HOTSPOT_ENABLED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hotspot Enabled ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public static void enable() {
    if(!isEnabled) {
        HotspotChangeReceiver.enable();
        MainActivity.getMpackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.getMcontext(), HotspotEnabledReceiver.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        isEnabled = true;
    }
}


public static void disable() {
    if(isEnabled) {
        HotspotChangeReceiver.disable();
        MainActivity.getMpackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.getMcontext(), HotspotEnabledReceiver.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        isEnabled = false;
    }
}
}
```

and broadcastreceiver when hotspot is disabled is following:

```
public class HotspotDisabledReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements Configurable {
public static boolean isEnabled = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //TODO handle properly
    if("net.wecodelicious.intent.action.HOTSPOT_DISABLED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hotspot Disabled ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public static void enable() {
    if(!isEnabled) {
        HotspotChangeReceiver.enable();
        MainActivity.getMpackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.getMcontext(), HotspotDisabledReceiver.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        isEnabled = true;
    }
}


public static void disable() {
    if(isEnabled) {
        HotspotChangeReceiver.disable();
        MainActivity.getMpackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.getMcontext(), HotspotDisabledReceiver.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        isEnabled = false;
    }
}
}
```

also I'm enabling all receiver components in ManiActivity as followed:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static boolean isF = true;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
enableall();
}

public static void enableall(){


    if(isF) {
        HotspotChangeReceiver.enable();
        HotspotEnabledReceiver.enable();
        HotspotDisabledReceiver.enable();
        isF=false;
    }
}
```

I've registered them in manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".HotspotChangeReceiver" android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".HotspotEnabledReceiver" android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="net.wecodelicious.intent.action.HOTSPOT_ENABLED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".HotspotDisabledReceiver" android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="net.wecodelicious.intent.action.HOTSPOT_DISABLED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But when i run the app and turn the hotspot on Toasts are displayed in following sequence:

```
Hotspot Changed
Hotspot Disabled
Hotspot Enabled
```

also when i turn the hotspot off following Toasts are displayed:

```
Hotspot Changed
Hotspot Disabled
Hotspot Changed
Hotspot Disabled
```

I hope someone recognizes the strange behavior and has a quick solution for it.I tried to find the solution but was unable to come up with any.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try observing what states the wifi goes through (either debugger or logging), clearly it's more than one simple state change.

Answer (score 0):

When you Enable and Disable, it is a State Change at the same time isn't it. I would either register Enable and Disable, or just State Change by itself only.